# Websocket over SSL (WSS) "Failed to upgrade" Elastic Beanstalk (ALB, Rails, Nginx, Actioncable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting a 404 failed to upgrade when trying to connect to a websocket deployed on EB behind an ALB. Most questions pertain to this on SO are left unanswered or unclear.

*Real domain replaced w/ example.com*

```
> new WebSocket('wss://example.com/cable');
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/cable' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Error in /var/app/current/log/production.log (lines shortened)

```
I, Started GET "/cable" 
I, Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] 
E, Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
I, Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket]
```

Setup

- Elastic Beanstalk + ALB (Puma with Ruby 2.4)
- HTTPS / WSS / SSL
- Rails 5

config/production.rb:

```
config.action_cable.url = "wss://usetreasure.com/cable"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ '/https:\/\/*/', '/http:\/\/*/' ]
```

on EB instance /etc/nginx/conf.d/websockets.conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix://var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;

  location /cable {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://puma;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

ALB is setup for 443 and 80 on HTTP / HTTPS (but on the security group shows TCP ?) 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrKb4.png)